# Travis CI/Android: Deploying .apk to S3

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm new with Travis-CI and having trouble getting the build to publish the resulting apk to S3.  Here is my .yml:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - android-25
    - build-tools-25.0.0
    - extra

    # Additional components
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-android-support
  licenses:
    - 'android.*'
  script:
     - ./gradlew clean build
  deploy:
     provider: s3
     bucket: "website"
     endpoint: "s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
     region: "us-west-2"
     upload-dir: "travis_apk"
     skip_cleanup: true
     edge: true
     access_key_id: $S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID
     secret_access_key: $S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
     local-dir: app/build/outputs/apk
```

The build completes successfully, but there is no indication in the Travis log that it tried to do anything with the deploy.  It does show at the beginning that it has set the env vars for the access keys, but nothing about a resulting .apk or that it tried to connect to S3.  Not sure there is anything of value here but this is the end of the log:

```
:app:packageDebugAndroidTest
:app:assembleDebugAndroidTest
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
:app:connectedAndroidTest
:app:connectedCheck
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 mins 51.075 secs
The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 0.
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

Any advice?

Thanks!